# How to shrink lines printed by SP300-2 (star micro dot matrix printer)

Tags: printing, printer, dot-matrix-printer

My old dot matrix printer (Star Micronics sp 300)  broke and I bought the same model and plugged in the parallel port as usual.

however, the printer prints this instead (the lines are spaced out) :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQbSj.jpg

Also the manual if you understand it : http://www.manualslib.com/manual/164989/Star-Micronics-Sp300.html

I'm thinking it has to do something with "control font" or "control code" to reset the number of lines.
I only have cmd DOS to work with since I do not have any more desktop computers or windows installed.

Anyone have any clue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but if I remember it right, on my old Star printer, you have to enter "Memory Switch" mode and set LPI (lines per inch) to a bigger number. You will be needing the user manual to guide you on how to enter this mode. The link above is a Programmer's manual.

Comment: Is it the dip switch? Per http://www.starmicronics.com/support/Mannualfolder/sp312im.pdf manual setting the switch to off goes to control code, but what do I do after that? How do I input the control codes?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong about the memory switch mode, it was on another model. On this model, I think it's set via dip switch. On the dip switch settings, for dip switch 1-5, set the paper feed length to 1/8 inch (OFF).

Comment: i tried this and nothing happened. i cracked open the old one and none of the dip switches were moved.  i think i need the printer to recognize that it needs to print less per line

Comment: i called star and its apparently my software problemm. basically ill need to install a new pos system.

Comment: Normally, print commands from software application programs temporarily override printer defaults. Since the same printer model, with the same defaults settings is used, it should have printed as usual. Maybe the LPI configuration in your software program was changed to lesser lines printed inch. You might like to check this out before buying/installing a new POS system.